# componentWillRecieveProps is not working for a component in a condition

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that i made and componentWillRecieveProps doesn't get called at all.

I think the problem is that i put the component inside a condition in the parent class because when i removed the condition the componentWillRecieveProps was called normally, don't get me wrong my component get rendered in both cases, it is just that the function doesn't called whatever i do, it was worth noting that componentDidUpdate worked normally with me.

the following code is for the condition i made in the parent component:

```
{this.state.mode != LISTMODE ? 
   <UserDetails
       userID = {this.state.choosenUserID}
       mode = {this.state.mode}
       changeUsersMode = {this.changeMode}/>
 : null}
```

and the following code is for the componentWillRecieveProps function:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if(nextProps.mode == EDITMODE){
        this.setState({
            user:{
                ...this.state.user,
                userName : "Tamer",
                firstName : "Tamer",
                lastName : "Mohamed",
                registrationNumber : "1",
                genderID : 0,
                typeID : 1,
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I hope someone helps me figure out what is going on.

Comment: can you post the whole code of your components ?

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps was previously deprecated. If you still need to use it, use UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps. If you need to update state, you can use the static method getDerivedStateFromProps

Comment: @Richard i am using  React 15 so it still have componentWillRecieveProps and it if working fine with other components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`componentWillRecieveProps` will be invoked only before a mounted component receives new props. That said, if you are removing a component from DOM using a condition based on state, and if the component again renders because of change in state, the component is newly rendered (i.e., mounted). The component is not in updated phase.